# Unable to retrieve Friend Key by his email Using FIrebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database like this

```
Users
  +oagnpangnangpadngn

  +psdpgpsdnpgndpsngpndap

  +pdgpjdpsgpdsjpgjpsdjpg

  --letssupposemyfriendkey     <----- I want this key

        --name Ahsan

        --email test@gmail.com
```

Now As you can see there is 2 child in each User.

I have already setup an on click button who get the email from layout when I input it in Edit Text. So mainly I want use that email I inputted to get User Key of that email .

e.g I inputted ----> test@gmail.com

Now how do I search users for this email and then get the key of user who has this email?

I am not Using Firestore or Cloud Functions, so if possible don't give me answers for that Im using Firebase Realtime Database in Android Studio using Java (Not Kotlin).

Comment: I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Please edit your post accordingly

Comment: I read it that's why I made sure The title is summary of my question and read my English again and again to see if its wrong the only reason I didn't provide code is that the question itself doesn't need a code to be provided since its not an error Plz Help if you think my question is still not good Plz

Comment: I'm sorry that you are struggling with this. The question is just not very well structured. English is rarely the problem. I have no clue about android, but with good android questions I can understand what the OP needs. Usually it is a good practise the question by describing the problem and add the code/error last. You can also look at the formatting of upvoted questions in your area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do requires the use of a database query. For example, here is how to find all users with a given ``email` value:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
Query friendQuery = usersRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo("test@gmail.com");
friendQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot friendSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(friendSnapshot.getKey()); // letssupposemyfriendkey
        System.out.println(friendSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class)); // Ahsan
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
}
```

I highly recommend spending some time in the [Firebase documentation on sorting and filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), taking the [Firebase codelab for Android developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/), and reading previous [questions about Firebase queries](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%5bandroid%5d%20query).

Comment: Thanks you thank you thankyou that's exactly what I was asking for thank you again :')